# XML View is not working

Tags: sapui5

I am pretty new to UI5 and following this tutorial http://openui5.org/getstarted.html. I am getting an issue in step 3 of this tutorial where I am creating XML view of the app. The data "Hello World" is not showing up on the page. When I looked into the console, I am seeing this error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js
```

Here is my code:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
      <title>Hello World</title>
      <script
       id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
       src='https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
       data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
       data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
       data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
       data-sap-ui-preload="async">
      </script>
      <script>
       sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function(){
       new sap.ui.xmlview({
       viewName: "sap.ui.demo.wt.App"
       }).placeAt("content");
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody">
      <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

App.view.xml

```xml
<mvc:View
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
  <Text text="Hello World!" />
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a View with the namespace `sap.ui.demo.wt`, but the framework doesn't know where to find this namespace.

You need to add this definition to you bootstrap-script-tag:

```
data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"sap.ui.demo.wt": "./"}'
```

---

Looking at the linked guide, I see that the code in the text doesn't have this declaration, however the code in the *Try it out yourself*-Box (and the linked [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O4ISRg)) does.